# Add a library in Spark in Bluemix & connect MongoDB , Spark together

Tags: python, apache-spark, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

**1)** I have Spark on Bluemix platform, how do I add a library there ?

I can see the preloaded libraries but cant add a library that I want.

Any command line argument that will install a library?

> pip install --package is not working there

**2)**  I have Spark and Mongo DB running, but I am not able to connect both of them.

> con ='mongodb://admin:ITCW....ssl=true'
>   ssl1 ="LS0tLS ....."
>   client = MongoClient(con,ssl=True)
>   db = client.mongo11 
>   collection = db.mongo11 
>   ff=db.sammy.find()

**Error I am getting is : 

SSL handshake failed: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:590)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Python notebook:

`!pip install <package>`

and then

`import <package>`

Comment: <b> > Thanks :)</b>

Comment: Langer ... Any idea about the 2nd question